# Roles and Permissions in Windows Forms

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, user-roles

I am wanting to update our current windows forms security to something a lot more flexible.

At the moment we have a single column in thew users table which is named 'Access_Level', this field holds an int value (1 to 4) which is then use to determine users access to certain areas of the application.

This worked fine when the system was small, but the system is growing rapidly now so I think it is a good time to update the user access and possibly introduce roles.

As a basic overview, the system is used in a number of shops and has a large number of users.
Each shop provides a number of different services, but not all shop provide all/the same as eachother.

Users need to be able to access the services applicable to the store they are logged in at.
Some users also need to be able to access 'admin' features for particular services.

We then have some higher level access which includes IT Support, Senior Managers and Auditors.

Can anyone suggest (or link to) a flexible, simple way of introducing this, in a way which will allow us to manage access permissions without always having to update the application code.

Thank you.

Comment: This might be related with SSO concept. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on. You can create an authentication webservice that will be used for all the clients.

Comment: Can this be used in Windows Forms though?

Comment: I put the same question on stackoverflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416113/sso-in-windows-forms

Answer (score 0):

See the solution for [SSO in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416113/sso-in-windows-forms)

"When a user logs in, you can also store in the Users table some unique ID of the PC (e.g. PC name, IP address, ...), on which the user is working. Every time an SSO-capable C# app starts on some PC, it can check in DB first whether the ID of the PC is present in the Users table (in the record of a logged-in user). If yes, then it can skip the login form, and e.g. show the name of the user it found as the current one.

You can set the granularity of the SSO to any level you want. For example, if a subnet address is stored in the Users table, then the users of the PCs in this subnet have to log-in only once. If the GUID of the current Windows user is stored, then logging out of Windows and logging in as a different user will require another log-in to the system."