# SSO in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, single-sign-on

I need to implement Single Sign On for two different C# Windows Forms apps

Do you know a good framework that does this ?

Comment: What is your authentication system? Can you use Windows auth?

Comment: No, I have to use users that I currently have in our DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user logs in, you can also store in the Users table some unique ID of the PC (e.g. PC name, IP address, ...), on which the user is working. Every time an SSO-capable C# app starts on some PC, it can check in DB first whether the ID of the PC is present in the Users table (in the record of a logged-in user). If yes, then it can skip the login form, and e.g. show the name of the user it found as the current one.

You can set the granularity of the SSO to any level you want. For example, if a subnet address is stored in the Users table, then the users of the PCs in this subnet have to log-in only once. If the GUID of the current Windows user is stored, then logging out of Windows and logging in as a different user will require another log-in to the system.

Comment: Thanks. This might be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a framework. Here's a guidance page from Microsoft that outlines the overall strategy to use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972971.aspx. Hopefully it can help get you started.